# What's its use of the nonsingular 2-step nilpotent Lie algebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

What's its use of the nonsingular 2-step nilpotent Lie algebras which form an a class of 2-step nilpotent Lie algebras ?

**Recall:** A $2$-step nilpotent Lie algebra $N$ is **non-singular** if $ad X : N \to Z$ is surjective for all $X\in N-Z$. Where $Z$ denote the center of $N$.
Here $ad X (Y) = [X,Y] \, $ for all $X,Y\in N$.

**Example:** The Heisenberg algebra is nonsingular.

Tank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonsingular $2$-step nilpotent Lie algebras are of special importance in geometry.
P. Eberlein, one of experts here, says it as follows: "Nonsingular and almost nonsingular Lie algebras are the most well behaved of all 2-step nilpotent Lie algebras". I think you should read one of his papers on [Geometry of $2$-step nilpotent Lie algebras](http://emerald.tufts.edu/as/math/Festschrift/eberleinarticle.pdf), to convince yourself of the "use".